# Spring MVC gives HTTP 406 for application/octet-stream

Tags: spring-mvc, http-headers, httpresponse, http-error

I am using Spring Web MVC and have written a controller that shall return binary data to a plugin in a web-page that show 3D content. This plugin uses STK files for it's models, so I have set-up my webapp to produce this kind of contents for *.stk URLs

The springDispatcherServlet is setup to handle *.stk requests in my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.stk</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/3dobject", produces="application/octet-stream")
public class Object3DController {

    @Autowired
    private DesignerService designerService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{article}.stk", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept: application/octet-stream")
    public void getObject3DForArticle(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String article) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        Object3D object = designerService.get3DModelForArticleNumber(article, LanguageCode.NORWEGIAN);
        byte[] content = object.getContent();
        response.setContentLength(content.length);
        IOUtils.write(content, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

When I try to access the data through a browser, I get the following error:

HTTP Status 406 - The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

I have deployed my app to a tomcat server on localhost.

Any ideas of what I must do to make the browser download the binary data?

PS! I changed from *.3do (3d object) to *.stk. With 3do it worked as expected, but the plugin fails with an error (which is hard to interpret), so I have to experiment in order to verify wether or not the URL extension matters...

Comment: I added the headers="Acceot: application/octet-stream" in the @RequestMapping annotation just for testing purposes. It did not change anything as expected. :)

Comment: The `HTTP` Request you are making has incorrect or missing _Accept_ header. The plugin needs to set the _Accept_ header to `application/octet-stream` in order to reach the controller that produces `application/octet-stream`

Comment: For the time being I am testing the URL with the browser only, which has an Accept header which includes \*/\*. I thought that meant that the browser would load anything..

Comment: FYI: The Accept header from the browser is Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,\*/\*;q=0.8

Comment: What is the plugin error?

Comment: It is a plugin used to opne inside the browser or you trying to download the file?

Comment: Please could you add more information about the plugin? I feel like there is something I'm missing. I don't understand why changing a file extension mapping in Spring would change the behaviour since the _Accept_ header sent by your browser would not change. You should be able to make a request using one of the methods in my answer, after adding the correct _Accept_ header, that tells the browser to download the data.

Comment: Well, I have not come so far as to test things with the plugin yet. I am only using the browser address bar to fetch the contents of the file. With a .3do extension it works (gets downloaded to my Downloads folder), with a .stk extension I get "The requested resource is not available."

Comment: I meant that I get "HTTP Error 406 Not acceptable"

Answer (score 0):

The [`RequestMapping.produces()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces%28%29) narrows the request and therefore is

> only mapped if the **Accept** matches one of these media types

So you need to set the corresponding **Accept** header in the request from the plugin. This cannot be done by simply making an HTTP GET Request by typing in a URL into a browser. One plugin I find useful for Chrome is the [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/). There are plenty of others that offer similar functionality. Alternatively try using [`cURL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to make the request with the correct header.

Comment: How does this explain the fact that it worked as expected through the browser with the *.3do extension?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that a request with `*.3do` in the URL on your browser returns correctly?

Comment: Yupp. It returns the correct binary data which the browser tries to save into my Downloads folder. But if I change to a .stk extension instead, it fails..